# Dynamic load data bootstrap table ajax

Tags: sql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to load data from my database to my table with bootstrap, using ajax, only when I change mySelect

```
$(".mySelect").change(function () {
var id_item     = $('#id_item').val();
$.ajax({
    url     : 'data.php',
    type    : 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data    :  {id_item:id_item},
    success: function( data ) {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: data
        });
    }
    ,
    error: function(data){
        alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works except data display on my table

Comment: can you just try `$('#table').html(data);` in your success and let us know what you get?

Comment: I tried this code, the header of my table disappears,

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please be more specific, we wouldn't know what do you mean by "header".

Comment: the headers are the name of the column, so when i change mySelect the columns disappears, before i had an empty table, now i have nothing, it's bizarre

Comment: That means there's nothing in your callback. You have got to let us see what you got in `data.php` then.

Comment: i have only 1 data in my database, i can see the json response when i change mySelect : [{"name":"alpha","data":"test 1"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution

$('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data);